# DOMXpath query to get the value only to next span tag

Tags: php, domxpath

I am reading in a page content with file_get_contents. This contains the following code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row1">
        <span>
            This is my first text
            <span class="xxx">mySubtext</span>
        </span>
        <a href="...">MyLink</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row1">
        <span>
            This is my first text 2
            <span class="xxx">mySubtext2</span>
        </span>
        <a href="...">MyLink</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I output only the text up to the second SPAN?

I use the following code and get mySubtext as well

```
$headerData = $xpath->query('//div[@class="row"]/div[@class="row1"]');
foreach ($headerData as $header) {
    $value = $xpath->query('span', $header);
    $value = $value->item(0)->textContent;
    echo $value;
}
```

Edit: I have updated the code to show the header area as well

Comment: What 's the value of the `$header` variable? I know, that it is a `DOMElement` instance. It would be good to know, how the markup of the whole `$header` document tree looks like.

Comment: The `textContent` property holds the text content of the node itself, plus that of any descendants - so you won't be able to do this by getting the "outer" span, and then checking its `textContent`. You will need to explicitly access the first text node child of the span.